# how to replace the value in one matrix from the other

Tags: r

I have two data frames:

df1:

```
Person|BreakfastSpent|LunchSpent|DinnerSpent
a     |100           |200       |21
b     |12            |65        |   
c     |14            |294       |46
d     |53            |          |55
e     |              |23        |7
f     |49            |54        |95
g     |61            |87        |47
h     |              |41        |32
i     |1             |          |107
```

and df2:

```
Person|Expenditure_BrkFast|Expenditure_Lunch|Expenditure_Dinner
a     |213                |79               |0
d     |265                |35               |543
f     |342                |98               |76
g     |119                |0                |0
```

I want to replace the `df1` values from `df2` values, if available. Can some tell me a short way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

As the columns are in the same order, we can use `Map` with `match` (assuming that the two datasets are `data.frame`s)

```
df1[-1] <- Map(function(x, y) replace(x, match(df2$Person, 
                  df1$Person, nomatch = 0), y), df1[-1], df2[-1])
```

---

Or another option is to use `row/column` indexing to assign

```
df1[-1][cbind(match(df2$Person, df1$Person), rep(1:3, each = nrow(df2)))] <- unlist(df2[-1])
df1
#  Person BreakfastSpent LunchSpent DinnerSpent
#1      a            213         79           0
#2      b             12         65          NA
#3      c             14        294          46
#4      d            265         35         543
#5      e             NA         23           7
#6      f            342         98          76
#7      g            119          0           0
#8      h             NA         41          32
#9      i              1         NA         107
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
names(df2) <- names(df1)
a <- df2[df2$Person %in% df1$Person, ]
b <- df1[!df1$Person %in% df2$Person, ]
rbind(a, b)
```